# Bug in awarding badges?

Tags: bug

7 hours ago, I got the "Revival" badge for my answer in this question,
 [In simple terms: what are the implications of homothetic and nonhomothetic consumer preferences?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/10285/61)

The Revival badge is awarded when

> "Answer more than 30 days after a question was asked **as first
>   answer** scoring 2 or more "

I did answer more than 30 days later, and scored 2 or more, but mine was not the first answer. An answer already existed. So why was I awarded the badge?

SE-associates please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct interpretation of the rule is different:

> "Answer more than 30 days after a question was asked as **(first answer scoring 2 or more)**"

The precise conditions do not always fit into one-line summaries gracefully, and this is an instance of that. The post [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) clarifies the conditions by breaking them into separate points:

> - Provide an answer to a question that is at least 30 days old at the time of answering.
> - Your answer reaches a score of two.
> - No other answers posted earlier than your answer have a score of two. "Earlier" refers to the time the answer was originally posted
>     (first revision).

(Aside: it also happens that [two answers to the same question earn Revival](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196936).)

Comment: Fun, this last one. Thanks Sally.